# Adding multiple TextView on runTime android

Tags: android, view, runtime

I'm trying to add multople TextViews to a relativeLayout on runtime.
the reason is that the list is to be created, depending on users choises.

I know how to add 1 textView. but when I entered the code to a loop and tried to creat more than 1, it just doesn't show anything..

pleas help,

```
 int left=70,top=25;
 for (String s:startLetterPos){
        params.leftMargin = left;
        top += 70;
        params.topMargin = top;
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setText(s);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv.setTextSize(20);

        testLayout.addView(tv);

    }
```

EDIT: the full code of the activity:

```
package com.fgdvir.psychowords;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WordTest extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout testLayout;
    int            displayWidth, displayHeight;
    ArrayList<String> startLetterPos = new ArrayList<String>();
    //private int[] startLetterPos = new int[26];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_test);

    startLetterPos = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("test");

    testLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.word_test);
    create_questions();
    // Get Screen size
    /*
     * Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); Point size = new `      `Point(); display.getSize(size);
     * displayWidth = size.x; displayHeight = size.y;
     */

}

public void create_questions() {
    int left=70,top=25;
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (String s:startLetterPos){
        params.leftMargin = left;
        top += 70;
        params.topMargin = top;
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setText(s);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv.setTextSize(20);

        testLayout.addView(tv);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: add code where this code execute.

Comment: I edited my code an added the full activity, but it is not really important because the same code, without the for (when it creats only one TextView) does work.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured it out,
I still don't know why this doesn't work, but I found another way.
I added the text to a linearLayout, and then the linearLayout to my relative layout:

```
LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(this);
    lL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++){
        String s = startLetterPos.get(i);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setText(s);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        if (i != 0 ){
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i-1);
        }

        lL.addView(tv,params);

    }
    testLayout.addView(lL);

}
```